# find to work with analyzing anonymous writer identification

Tags: javascript, c#, c++

I want to design author identification but don't know how it works.
here is the online tool that is doing something like that... but its working??
http://www.aicbt.com/authorship-attribution/online-software/

```
void main()
    try
    {
        main program
    }
    catch exception
    {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Don't add random language tags.

Comment: oky sir , i'll care next time

Comment: You can even care this time! Editing is as easy as never before! Go ahead and try it! :-)

Comment: In C++, the `main` function returns `int`.  Always.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Nitpicky but doesn't that only hold true for strictly-conforming programs? I think the implementation is allowed to offer a `void main`. And for freestanding implementations it might be a whole different matter. Maybe I'm confusing this with the C standard, though...